# How to efficinetly combine dataframe rows based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset, which contains a column with the cluster number, the number of observations in that cluster and the maximum value of another variable x grouped by that cluster.

```
clust = np.arange(0, 10)
obs = np.array([1041, 544, 310, 1648, 1862, 2120, 2916, 5148, 12733, 1])
x_max = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[clust, obs, x_max], columns=['clust', 'obs', 'x_max'])

   clust    obs  x_max
0      0   1041     10
1      1    544     20
2      2    310     30
3      3   1648     40
4      4   1862     50
5      5   2120     60
6      6   2916     70
7      7   5148     80
8      8  12733     90
9      9      1    100
```

My task is to combine the `clust` row values with adjasent rows, so that each cluster contains at least 1000 observations.
My current attempt gets stuck in an infinite loop because the last cluster has only 1 observation.

```
condition = True
while (condition):
    condition = False
    for i in np.arange(0, len(df) + 1):
        if df.loc[i, 'x'] < 1000:
            df.loc[i, 'id'] = df.loc[i, 'id'] + 1
            df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'x': 'sum', 'y': 'max'})
            condition = True
            break
```

Is there perhaps a more efficient way of doing this? I come from a background in SAS, where such situations would be solved with the `if last.row` condition, but it seems here is no such condition in python.
The resulting table should look like this

```
clust obs     x_max
0     1041    10
1     2502    40
2     1862    50
3     2120    60
4     2916    70
5     5148    80
6     12734   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way. A vectorize way here is difficult to implement, but using for loop on an array (or a list) will be faster than using `loc` at each iteration. Also, not a good practice to change `df` within the loop, it can only bring problem.

```
# define variables
s = 0   #for the sum of observations
gr = [] #for the final grouping values
i = 0   #for the group indices

# loop over observations from an array
for obs in df['obs'].to_numpy():
    s+= obs
    gr.append(i)
    # check that the size of the group is big enough
    if s>1000:
        s = 0
        i+=1
# condition to deal with last rows if last group not big enough 
if s!=0:
    gr = [i-1 if val==i else val for val in gr]    
    
# now create your new df
new_df = (
    df.groupby(gr).agg({'obs':sum, 'x_max':max})
      .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'cluster'})
)
print(new_df)
#    cluster    obs  x_max
# 0        0   1041     10
# 1        1   2502     40
# 2        2   1862     50
# 3        3   2120     60
# 4        4   2916     70
# 5        5   5148     80
# 6        6  12734    100
```